# Mostar la fecha inicial y final

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo una tabla cabecera y cabecera detalle, en mi cabecera tengo el id del cliente y en mi cabecera detalle tengo todos los meses que el cliente realizo un pago.

En mi Cabecera tengo el Id **1** y en mi detalle tengo los siguientes registros
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien bonito,pero lo que tengo que hacer es  mostrar solo la tercera columna y en el caso que haya varios meses en un año y mes como por ejemplo el 2022  - 1 tiene varios meses que pago el cliente, en ese caso la tercera columna debería de mostrar solo el primer mes que pago y el ultimo mes como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo he creado un store para poder hacer el agrupado pero lo hice con un ciclo while, el problema viene que yo tengo que hacer por cada cliente y son muchos clientes y esto hace que  el store tome mucho tiempo.

> 

```
        SET LANGUAGE Spanish;
        
        INSERT INTO #PAGO (Ano, Mes, PeriodoCobertura)
        SELECT  YEAR(FechaOperacion), MONTH(FechaOperacion),    DescripcionPeriodoCobertura
        FROM    dbo.PAGO_MENSUALES
        WHERE   CodigoDocumento = @CodigoDocumento
                AND CodigoOperacion = 0 -- Pago de Cuota
                and MontoMovimientoCI >0 
        ORDER BY 1, 2
    
            -- obtiene la fila inicial y final
        SET @Fila_Pago = 1
        SELECT  @Filas_Pago = ISNULL(MAX(NumeroRegistro), 0) 
        FROM    #PAGO
        -- obtiene los datos iniciales
        SELECT  @AnoActual_Pago = Ano, 
                @MesActual_Pago = Mes
        FROM    #PAGO
        WHERE   NumeroRegistro = @Fila_Pago
        SET @DescripcionActual_Pago = ''
        SET @DescripcionFechaInicial_Pago = ''
        SET @DescripcionFechaFinal_Pago = ''
        SET @DescripcionDefinida_Pago = ''

        BEGIN TRY
        WHILE @Fila_Pago <= @Filas_Pago
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @Ano_Pago = Ano, 
                    @Mes_Pago = Mes, 
                    @PeriodoCobertura = PeriodoCobertura
            FROM    #PAGO
            WHERE   NumeroRegistro = @Fila_Pago
            IF (@AnoActual_Pago = @Ano_Pago) AND (@MesActual_Pago = @Mes_Pago)
            begin
                SET @DescripcionActual_Pago = @DescripcionActual_Pago + @PeriodoCobertura + '/'
            end 
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @DescripcionActual_Pago = LEFT(@DescripcionActual_Pago, LEN(@DescripcionActual_Pago) - 1)

                IF CHARINDEX('/' , @DescripcionActual_Pago) > 0
                BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO  #Pagos_No_PAGADOS(descFecha )
                SELECT Codigo FROM ufn_Split(@DescripcionActual_Pago, '/')

                UPDATE #Pagos_No_PAGADOS
                SET descFechaEdit ='1-' + descFecha

                UPDATE  #Pagos_No_PAGADOS
                SET descFechaEdit = replace(descFechaEdit,'set' , 'sep')
                
                UPDATE  #Pagos_No_PAGADOS
                SET valFecha = convert(DATETIME, descFechaEdit, 102)
                SELECT TOP 1 @DescripcionFechaFinal_Pago  =  descFecha   FROM #Pagos_No_PAGADOS ORDER BY valFecha DESC -- group by 1
                SELECT TOP 1 @DescripcionFechaInicial_Pago =  descFecha  FROM #Pagos_No_PAGADOS ORDER BY valFecha ASC -- group by 1
                SET @DescripcionActual_Pago = @DescripcionFechaInicial_Pago  + '/' +  @DescripcionFechaFinal_Pago
                SET @DescripcionDefinida_Pago =  @DescripcionFechaFinal_Pago
                DELETE FROM #Pagos_No_PAGADOS
            END 
                declare @PagoObtenido varchar(25),
                @FechaGenerada varchar(40),
                @AnioCoberturaObtenido varchar(12)

                set @FechaGenerada = CONCAT( @AnoActual_Pago , '-', @MesActual_Pago , '-1')
                set @PagoObtenido =  substring(FORMAT(convert(datetime, @FechaGenerada, 102) , 'MMM') , 1 ,3 )
                set @PagoObtenido= UPPER(LEFT(@PagoObtenido, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@PagoObtenido, 2, LEN(@PagoObtenido)))
                set @AnioCoberturaObtenido =  FORMAT(convert(datetime, @FechaGenerada, 102) , 'yy')
                set @DescripcionDefinida_Pago =  CONCAT( @PagoObtenido,'-', @AnioCoberturaObtenido)

                INSERT INTO #CoberturaConcatenado_Pago
                                (Ano, Mes,  PeriodoCobertura , PeriodoCoberturaModificada)
                VALUES      (@AnoActual_Pago, @MesActual_Pago, @DescripcionDefinida_Pago , @DescripcionActual_Pago)
                SET @AnoActual_Pago = @Ano_Pago
                SET @MesActual_Pago = @Mes_Pago
                SET @DescripcionActual_Pago = @PeriodoCobertura + '/'
                SET @DescripcionDefinida_Pago =''
        END
            SET @Fila_Pago = @Fila_Pago + 1
    END
```

Comment: Podrías añadir el stored-procedure junto a las cabeceras de la primera tabla?
para poder darte una solucion personalizada, Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la definición de las tablas junto con datos de prueba? No estoy seguro si la columna de mes pagado es fecha o cadena. Esto es un problema de islas y valles que tiene varias soluciones bastante eficientes.

Comment: acabo de agregar el sp, el problema es el  while porque hay mas de 1000 clientes y por cada cliente debe de ingresar y validar sus pagos,

Answer (score 0):

No era necesaria tanta logica, elimine todo el ciclo while y lo trabaje con un insert a una tabla, despues lo agrupe por año y mes y solo quedo poner los maximos y minimos